# What can I do if I can't find driver's for my computer's NIC

Tags: windows, drivers, network-adapter

This is driving me bananas, I've burned something like 10 CD's trying to find an EXE or ZIP that will work for my dad's computer [my old one]

I'm about ready to give up, is there any sort of generic driver software I can find.

For what its worth the motherboard is kt4v 6712 ver 10a [for future people googling and finding this page without a link to working drivers, I apologize]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: [VIA Rhine Family Driver - v1.13A](http://www.viaarena.com/Driver/rhine_win7_v1.13a.zip).That should be what you are looking for. It's it from the VIA officially webpage. So, it should be safe to download. If those dont work then try this searching via [VIA's Official Driver Portal](http://www.via.com.tw/en/support/drivers.jsp).

*Note: Drivers linked were for Windows 7 64-bit. Use the second link to search via the correct OS.*

Answer (score 0):

The product page says it uses the VIA VT6103. Just find a driver for that.